# Question Limit due to questions not being received well

Tags: bug, asking-questions, post-ban

Yesterday I asked two questions for the first time on the Maths Stack. The initial question was well received and I was given many helpful answers. However, my [second question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3308023/vectors-and-ratios) was less well received. I believe it was due to being borderline, if not, a homework question and the unedited version contained very few of my own thoughts or working from attempts at the question. Truth was though, that I was struggling with the question for several hours and any of the work I attempted would have been convoluted and not helpful to those answering the question. The question itself was also unclear as I myself then did not understand the maths required to answer my question and thus all I could ask was to ask someone to show me how to solve it so I could learn the method and type of maths from their answer.

Today, however, I came up with a question which I truly believe could be of positive potential. Yet when I tried asking a question, I was told brought to a page informing me that some of my previous questions (obviously the one I mentioned in this post) were not received well and thus I would receive a cool down time of 24 hours before I could ask a new question. This page also included a message telling me that I should use the time to revisit my questions that were not well received and try to improve them. I feel this is slightly unjust as once my question received downvotes, I edited it multiple times to try to improve it and in addition to that, there were no significant amount of comments that told me how I could improve the question as this page suggested there may be: *"Use this time to revisit your previous questions, editing to address any issues that folks have pointed out in comments. "* In essence, I already tried doing that.

This small rant was the build up to two questions:

**What exactly determines who receives a 24 hour question cool down?** I presume it is the downvotes. If so, **how many downvotes would result in it happening?**

The page stated that I would be able to ask questions again in 1 day. I assume that is 24 hours. **My question was asked at 5 a.m. in my timezone yesterday and today is 7 a.m. yet I still cannot ask any new questions– why may this be the case?** Is this a possible bug or is the "1 day" approximated?

Comment: I have added the tag, post-ban. If you click on that, it may show you a list of previous posts on that topic, which (even if the questions are not the same as yours) may provide you with some useful information.